# How to restoring the Registered Server window in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Is there some way to restore the Registered Server window in SSMS ?

I don't mean restoring the individual server details, rather I mean the actual window

I've tried clicking the menu item "View \ Registered Servers" and the keyboard short-cut CTRL + ALT + G, but neither displays the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try going to menu Window \ Reset Window Layout. I have had to do that on a few computers that would not bring up the Registered Services window.

Comment: Excellent, that worked a treat.  Many thanks as this has been bugging me for a long while   :-)